# Send a value to C in android ndk and get sample (if) response

Tags: java, android, c, android-ndk

i write this code in my android Activity to send a request to C in android ndk:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),Calculate("1")+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

public native String Calculate(String j_key_name);
```

and in ndk side in C file i write this code:

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_org_sample_aguar_NActivity_Calculate(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jstring j_key_name) {

    if (j_key_name == "1") {
        return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, " its 1 ");
    } else{
        return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, " it's not 1 ");
    }
}
```

i don't have any error But That's always run else part and when i send "1" in response i get (it's not 1 ).

Answer (score 2):

> I have written simple if-else program in c. I use String.h library in
>   it and working correctly.

```
#include<string.h>
char j_key_name[] ="1";

int check = strcmp(j_key_name, "1");
if (check == 0) {
    printf("if");
} else{
    printf("else");
}
```

> Let's try above code. Hopefully solve your issue. Thanks in advance.